# Why does creating SimpleImmutableMap cause unchecked cast warning?

Tags: java, generics, unchecked-cast

In the following pretty simple code:

```
public static void test(Map<Externalizable, Externalizable> t){
    for(Map.Entry<Externalizable, Externalizable> e : t.entrySet()){
      //The next line causes unchecked cast warning
      Object o = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
  }
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/2777F1)

Why? The `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableMap` is a generic class. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Instead, use the [diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)

```
Object o = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```